# PHP Error : Undefined Index

Tags: php

This is going to sound really stupid, but I cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

Notice: Undefined index: o in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webres\OC_defaults.php

```
    $o = !empty($o) ? $o : $_REQUEST['o'];
    $ST_defaults["office"] = !empty($o) ? strtoupper($o) : $officeDefault;
    extract($ST_defaults);
```

Thanks,
Jatin

Comment: `$_REQUEST['o']` is not set.

Comment: Are you expecting `o` to be passed to your page via the query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`o` is not defined in the associative array `$_REQUEST`.

You can check if it is defined by using `isset($_REQUEST['o'])`.

Comment: Hi Fabien, I did isset() and it does not show that error now. But where does it show the checked value.

Comment: isset checks if the value is set. If it returns false, the value is not set. Now your problem is that that value is not set, you need to figure out why not. How is 'o' supposed to be passed to your page? GET or POST?

Comment: Thanks will have a look and if i get some problems I will re post it here.

Answer (score 2):

$_REQUEST['o'] is not set.
.. a simple fix would be to add

```
if(!array_key_exists('o',$_REQUEST)){$_REQUEST['o']='';};
```

oh, also, don't use $_REQUEST, its bad practice, its lazy, where the data comes is unknown, corruption/overwriting is possible~

use $_COOKIE / $_POST / $_GET instead..